# How to convert .shp file into an array?

Tags: c#, gis, shapefile

I am using EasyGis.net to load a shape file in my desktop application.
I want to save this file in database so that i can use this file from the server side of my software.
I am able to save normal .png files in database by converting image object into a byte array.
Now i need to save the shape file so that i can use this from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

`File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);`

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I also want to load this shape file , then how do i read this byte array and then show the .shp file in my wpf canvas?

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.shp", arrBytes);`